# Comparing dates stored as strings in Django

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

I had in my database containing a column of dates stored in string format (varchar) like `"12-Mar-2011"`, `"11-Apr-2012"`, etc. Is there a way to compare these dates in Django?

In `models.py`, the column is defined as string format. eg:

```
startdate = models.CharField(max_length=11)
```

Now I have to compare these dates with a date. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In your `models.py`, add a method that returns a `datetime` object, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # other fields

    def startdate_as_date(self):
        return dt.strptime(self.startdate,'%d-%b-%Y')
```

I've omitted some error checking (like making sure there is a startdate set) and checking if the date is a valid date or not - you should add these later.

Now you can do this:

```
foo = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
the_date = foo.startdate_as_date()
```

Now `the_date` is a `datetime` object which you can use to do the normal comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply. But now can I use the_date as like   obj = SomeModel.filter(the_date__gte=givenDate)  ?

Comment: No, in order to do that you'll have to do a migration of your database and change the type in the model, as Francis suggested.

Comment: Now is there any way other than migration as temporary fix for comparing the date stored as strings in database ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer you are looking for, but...

You **really** should migrate your DB to using a `models.DateField` type.

aside from that,

```
objects = YourModel.objects.raw("""
    SELECT 
        STR_TO_DATE(your_string_date_field, '%e-%b-%Y') AS a_mysql_date_field,
        *
    FROM your_table
    """)
```

does a raw query to get the string dates as actual mysql dates, maybe you can use it to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: What U suggested is 100% right. we have to do migration. But right now I am searching for a temporary fix for this problem. The Problem with raw objects is they cannot be paginated. even we can't write len(obj) for them to write our own paginating functions

Answer (score 0):

You can also use annotations to create a new virtual field, containing your value in a datetime format.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
Yourmodel.objects.annotate(startdate_datetime = RawSQL("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%%d-%%b-%%Y')", ())
```

Note that:

- STR_TO_DATE must be supported by your database. As far as I know, MySQL and PostgreSQL have this function.
- There are double `%` because the RawSQL function actually does some formatting internally, so `%` must be escaped.
- The field value will be `None` if you request is not valid. For instance, if you are using unexisting format characters, or invalid format values. e.g. if you try to make `%m` match with a month greater than 12 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do exactly what you want without raw SQL by creating a custom manager using Func, Value, and MySQL's STR_TO_DATE function and adding this manager to your model and then filtering on that.  If you are using a different database backend other than MySQL or MariaDB, you may need to change the function string and pattern that you feed to Func accordingly.

**managers.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Value, Func

class WeirdDateManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            start_date = Func(
                Value('start_date_string'),
                Value('%d-%b-%Y'),
                function='STR_TO_DATE',
            ),
        )
        return queryset
```

**models.py:**

```
from .managers import WeirdDateManager

class WeirdDateModel(models.Model):

    objects = WeirdDateManager()

    start_date_string = models.CharField(db_column="startdate", max_length=11) # I've renamed your field here so that I can use the start_date name to filter on the actual date, not the string.
```

**views.py:**

```
from .models import WeirdDateModel

objects = WeirdDateModel.objects.filter(start_date__gte = given_date)
```